# SQL Server - Find last time user defined function (UDF) was called

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, is there any way to find the last time a user defined function was called?

Comment: Did you google "sql server last time function was used"?

Comment: Fun fact: when you Google "SQL find the last time a function was called" this is actually the top result.  +1 because the answer is useful.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are using SQLServer 2016,its tricky

For [SQLserver 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt429371.aspx),You can use..

```
sys.dm_exec_function_stats
```

which will provide

[image]

If you are not using SQLServer 2016,you can follow below approach,but it is very tricky..

Pseudo code below

1.Query plan cache ,like below..

```
select * from
sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY 
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) st
where st.text like '%functionname%'
```

2.The above query provides,last execution time,but this can be reset ,so you can be out of luck and won't get reliable information,if server is restarted

Comment: Note that this view will NOT return any rows for table valued functions and scalar functions that are inlined.